# Inequality between string characters in python

Tags: python, string, inequality

I am new to StackOverflow so forgive me if I did any formatting wrong.

I am trying to extract the largest substring (with variable name 'longest_string') which follows an alphabetical order (i.e. a,b,x,y,z is valid, but a,c,b is not) from a string (with variable name 's').

What I tried to do is to create a loop which looped over every single character in '**s**', and assigned the first character of string **s** to the variable '**current_value**' and add it into a list called '**strings**'. Then, I compare the subsequent character to see if that character is larger than or equal to the **current_value**. If it is, then I add it to '**strings**', and if it isn't, I assigned the initial '**strings**' list to the '**longest_string**' list and refreshed the variable '**current_value**' and '**strings**'. Each time the subsequent character is smaller than the '**current_value**', the length of current '**strings**' is compared with the '**longest_string**' and the longest one is assigned as '**longest_string**'.

What I understand is that Python assumes that the first alphabet in the 26 English character to be the smallest (i.e. 'a' > 'z' will return False). However, when I run the below code:

```
s = 'zcbobobegghakl'
longest_string = None
current_value = None
strings = []

for i in s:
    if not current_value:
        current_value = i
        strings.append(i)
        continue

    if i >= current_value:
        strings.append(i)

    if i < current_value:
        if not longest_string or len(longest_string) < len(strings):
            longest_string = strings
        current_value = i
        strings = []
        
print(longest_string)
```

I get this output instead:

```
['o', 'b', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'g', 'h']
```

Why is it that the character 'b' got assigned into the same string as 'o' when clearly 'b' > 'o' will return False and thus make the 2nd IF statement False, wouldn't it not execute the 2nd IF statement in the first place?

Comment: Thinking this problem from `in sequence` perspective - like numbers. It'll be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this into the beginnig of the loop. Maybe this will give you some insight?

```
...
for i in s:
    print(i, current_value, strings)
    if not current_value:
...
```

> Why is it that the character 'b' got assigned into the same string as 'o'

`current_value` only decreases, and after you encounter first `b` accumulation continues until `a` is found

Comment: Ahhh, I did not consider the fact that any character which follows the alphabetical order after current_value can themselves be not following the order, (i.e. b > o > c) still satisfied my condition. Thanks for the insight!!